# Альтернатива (?|) для Java

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

```
final String regex = "(?|\"([^\"]+)\"|(\\S+))";
```

На такую регулярку машина выдаёт

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unknown inline modifier near index 2
(?|"([^"]+)"|(\S+))
```

Есть ли альтернатива данной конструкции?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [регулярных выражениях Java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) группы со сбросом индексов захватывающих групп (*branch reset group*) не поддерживаются.

Используйте `"\"([^\"]+)\"|(\\S+)"` и берите совпадения из подмасок, если значение подмаски не равно `null`:

```
String s = "\"abc\" def \"ghi jkl\"";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]+)\"|(\\S+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        results.add(matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        results.add(matcher.group());
    }
} 
System.out.println(results); // => [abc, def, ghi jkl]
```

См. [пример работы кода на Java](https://ideone.com/2HYiBP).